Convert a pure Python list of lists to a numpy array of pure python lists (of 1 dimension)
I have a list of a certain Python object (let's call it MyClass) that can be interpreted as a multi-dimensional Numpy array. However, I'd like to convert that list to a numpy array of MyClass, and not try to convert MyClass to an inner Numpy array. Just for the sake of the question, you can use a simple list instead of MyClass:
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

data = [a, b]

You can achieve what I want with:
import numpy

arr = np.empty(len(data), dtype=object)
for i,v in enumerate(data):
    arr[i] = v
assert arr.shape == (len(data),) # Works

But I'm surprised as to why this doesn't work:
arr = np.array(data, dtype=object)
print(arr.shape) # prints (2 ,3), and I want (2,)

Is there a way I can limit Numpy to not delve into the inner lists and instantiate them as arrays? Why isn't dtype=object argument implies that? I really hope to avoid that i,v enumerating loop.

Why do you want a numpy array? Whats the problem if the shape has extra dimensions? Sounds like an XY question...

Does it work with MyClass ? Does MyClass inherit from list. The behaviour is not surprising it is expected to convert nested list into matrix.

I need a very specific shape for my array of MyClass, as I'm using it for an xarray.Dataset.

That create and fill approach has been the recommended method for many years.

Another option is to use fromiter:
In [13]: data
Out[13]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [14]: arr = np.fromiter(data, dtype=object, count=len(data))

In [15]: arr
Out[15]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)

In [16]: arr.shape
Out[16]: (2,)


Numpy detects that your lists all have the same length and infers that it can create multiple dimensions.
If you were to have different lengths, this would work as expected. For example you could prepend an empty list and remove this element afterwards:
arr = np.array([[]]+data, dtype=object)[1:]
print(arr.shape) # (2,)

You could use your original method, without the loop:
arr = np.empty(len(data), dtype=object)
arr[:] = data

# array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)

Now, I'm not sure why you need an array of lists, but be aware that it might be more efficient not to use numpy at all and stick to python lists.
